# Prove that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded if and only if there is $M∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|≤M$ for all $x∈A$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded if and only if there is $M∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|≤M$ for all $x∈A$.

Help me understand this question I don't have any idea where to start.

Comment: what's your definition of a set being bounded? I think it's usually defined as exactly what you are trying to prove

Comment: @user160738, see https://books.google.com/books?id=dgvdCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22Prove+that+a+subset+A+of+R++is+bounded+if+and+only+if+there+is+%22&source=bl&ots=I74aBfPr9a&sig=EdC7rWPOoKHhMOJOd91owD0P9vU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic-4rGsN7RAhXI7YMKHeRmCqkQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Prove%20that%20a%20subset%20A%20of%20R%20%20is%20bounded%20if%20and%20only%20if%20there%20is%20%22&f=false -- the definition is given at the beginning of the section.

Comment: That book is the book I am using for this problem I am just reading through it wondering what the proof looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proofs like this depend crucially on how things are defined.  In this case, the problem comes from a book (see the link in my comment below the OP) in which a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is said to be *bounded* if it bounded both *above* and *below*, where $A$ is *bounded above* if there is a number $M$ such that $x\le M$ for all $x\in A$, and *bounded below* if there is a number $L$ such that $L\le x$ for all $x\in A$.

The proof now amounts to putting these definitions together with a property of the absolute value function, namely $-|x|\le x\le |x|$, along with a property of inequalties, namely that if $|x|\le M$, then $-M\le-|x|$, so that

$$|x|\le M\implies -M\le-|x|\le x\le|x|\le M$$

Thus $A$ is bounded above (by $M$) because $|x|\le M$ for all $x\in A$ implies $x\le M$ for all $x\in A$, and likewise bounded below (by $L=-M$) because $|x|\le M$ for all $x\in A$ implies $-M\le x$ for all $x\in A$.  Finally it follows that $A$ is *bounded* by the book's definition of "bounded."

**Remark**: One subtlety in all this is that the proof given above depends not just on knowing the book's definition of "bounded" but also on knowing certain facts about inequalities and the absolute value function.  Presumably, though, the relevant properties were established in earlier sections of the book.

Comment: I almost have this written down exactly but the iff statement throws me off because you then have to prove the converse

Answer (score 0):

That what you stated is literally the definition of a bounded set.
I mean you could try and assume the opposite: that for every x from A  there exists y from A such that $y>x$ but then you easily achieve contradiction, that A is in that case unbounded.
And the other way around if A is bounded that means that there exists a number M such that it is greater or equal than all of the members of the set, which I guess completes it.

Comment: Still confused a bit i been confused on this problem for 3 hours today

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|x|\leq M$ means $$-M \leq x \leq M$$ that means every $x$ in $A$ is smaller than $M$ (i.e. $A$ is bounded from above by $M$) and every $x$ in $A$ greater than $-M$ (i.e. $A$ is bounded from below by $-M$).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with another definition of boundedness: $A\subset\Bbb R$ is bounded iff $A$ is a subset of some interval, i.e. $a\le x\le b$ for some $a,b$ and for any $x\in A$. Now it is rather easy to find $M$ to fulfil $|x|\le M$. Try to play with $|a|$, $|b|$, some maximum etc. It could happen that both $a,b$ are negative and so on.

The bound $|x|\le M$ could be strongly unoptimal from one side. See $A=(2,3)$. Then $|x|\le3$ for any $x\in A$, but saying the truth, $|x|\le 3\iff -3\le x\le 3$.

Comment: But how does this help me write the proof?

Comment: As the other colleagues said, you should start with any definition of boundedness. I proposed to pass from the optimal one to the unoptimal, but intuitive (i.e. $|x|\le M$)

Answer (score 0):

> **1)** $ \emptyset \neq A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, $A$ is bounded $\leftrightarrow$ $\exists M \in \Bbb{R}:\forall x \in A: |x| \leq M$

**proof 1)**

> "$\leftarrow$" $|x| \leq M \to -M\leq x\leq M$ with $x \in A$, then
>   $A$ is bounded
>
> "$\rightarrow$" $A$ is bounded then $\exists S\in \Bbb{R}: \forall u
>  \in A: u \leq S$ and $\exists s \in \Bbb{R}: \forall w\in A: s\leq w$.
>   I define $T:=\max_\leq\{|S|,|s|\}$ and we have:
>
> - $s\leq x \leq S$ with $x \in A$
> - $s\leq |s|$ and $-s\leq |s|$ (then $-|s| \leq s$)
> - $S \leq |S|$ and $-S\leq |S|$
> - $|S| \leq T$ and $|s| \leq T$ (then $-T\leq -|s|$)
>
> then $$-T\leq-|s|\leq s \leq x \leq S \leq |S| \leq T \to -T \leq x
>  \leq T \to x \leq |T| \text{, with } x \in A$$

Comment: I don't understand the converse part can you explain it to me

Comment: [Def. $\Bbb{R}\supseteq A\neq\emptyset$, $A$ ist bounded if $A$ is bounded above (namely $\exists S\in\Bbb{R}:\forall x\in A:x\leq S$) and $A$ is bounded below (namely $\exists s\in\Bbb{R}:\forall x\in A:s\leq x$)] By Hypothesis of converse you have $\exists M\in\Bbb{R}:\forall x \in A:|x|\leq M$ namely $\exists M\in\Bbb{R}:\forall x\in A:-M\leq x\leq M$ (and $-M\in\Bbb{R}$), then by Def. you have $A$ is bounded because $A$ is bounded above (namely $\exists S\in\Bbb{R}:\forall x\in A:x\leq S$ with $S=M$) and $A$ is bounded below (namely $\exists s\in\Bbb{R}:\forall x\in A:s\leq x$ with $s=-M$)